# How to prevent Mach-O Linker Error on iOS App?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have downloaded an App that I need to work on from a colleague, but whenever I try to run it to test on Xcode, the build fails with 53 errors, all pertaining to the "Apple Mach-O Linker Error, X referenced from:" type.

[image]

I'm completely new to iOS development and Xcode as an IDE, so maybe I'm missing something incredibly basic.

For more info, I am also working with the [Neoflix](https://codecanyon.net/item/neoflix-react-native-theme/23182633) template.

What can I do to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to library or framework that you are using related to Facebook and React native is not Found.

First you need to remove all the framework that is used.
to Remove follow below Steps.

- select your Project Target.
- go to Embedded Library.
- Remove all Framework Related to Facebook and Rect native.
- again add
- also do this for Build settings of Project target and Embedded link 
  libraries.